# Socketio proxied throught Kong - Client connection keep closing

Tags: socket.io, kong

Summary

Client socket connection keeps getting disconnected, reconnect, disconnected, .... and so on

Steps To Reproduce

I am using Kong (https://github.com/Kong/kong) as a API gateway. The websocket server is proxied through Kong

- Websocket server: http://192.168.99.100:9696
- Kong proxy:

  - Server: http://192.168.99.100:9000
  - API:
  - upstream: http://192.168.99.100:9696
  - uris: /api/socket.*
  - strip uris: yes

Additional Details & Logs
In picture: left terminal is server, right is client. Client log shows:

`engine.io-client:socket socket close with reason: "transport close" +6s
  socket.io-client:manager onclose +1ms
  socket.io-client:manager cleanup +0ms
  socket.io-client:socket close (transport close) +0ms`

[image]

P/s: Tried with a nginx proxy instead of Kong, and it works fine, the client socket connection stays without being closed.

Comment: we have exactly this issue, is it a config issue ?

Comment: Still stuck on this. I added an issue on Kong Github repo, but no anwser yet. Temporary switching to pure Nginx now.

Comment: @DucAnh Did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having this issue and would like to contribute a possible clue for anybody stumbling on this. In my case, the reason behind the disconnection is the fact that KONG (or something between KONG and my browser) is stripping away the vital `Connection: keep-alive` and `Keep-Alive: timeout=5` response headers. Socket IO does send a request header of `Connection: keep-alive`, but KONG seems to ignore it.

There is also an issue reported on GitHub that may be worth tracking:
https://github.com/Kong/kong/issues/3008

We're currently investigating this and will update here if we find anything.